# Nodemon crashes

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I try to deploy js application but cannot start nodemon for some reason:

```
 nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node user.server.js`
file:///var/www/html/socioboard/socioboard-api/User/middleware/recent- 
visited.middleware.js:73
    const category = request?.baseUrl?.replace('/v1/', '') || ' ';
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:140:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the file it points to:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import RecentVisitedModel from '../../Common/Mongoose/models/recent-visited.js';
import { phproutes } from '../../Common/Shared/recent.visited.shared.js';

const recentVisitedModel = new RecentVisitedModel();

export default (request, response, next) => {
 /* #swagger.ignore = true */
const requestStart = Date.now();
const oldWrite = response.write;
const oldEnd = response.end;
const chunks = [];
let body;

response.write = function (chunk) {
chunks.push(chunk);

return oldWrite.apply(response, arguments);
};
response.end = function (chunk) {
if (chunk) chunks.push(chunk);
if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunks))
  body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
oldEnd.apply(response, arguments);
};
let requestErrorMessage = null;
const getError = (error) => {
requestErrorMessage = error.message;
};

request.on('error', getError);
const logClose = () => {
removeHandlers();
log(request, response, 'Client aborted.');
};
const logError = (error) => {
removeHandlers();
log(request, response, error.message);
};
const logFinish = () => {
removeHandlers();
log(request, response, requestErrorMessage);
};

response.on('close', logClose);
response.on('error', logError);
response.on('finish', logFinish);
const removeHandlers = () => {
//  request.off("data", getChunk);
// request.off("end", assembleBody);
request.off('error', getError);
response.off('close', logClose);
response.off('error', logError);
response.off('finish', logFinish);
};
const log = (request, response, errorMessage) => {
try {
  const {
    rawHeaders, httpVersion, method, socket, url,
  } = request;
  const { remoteAddress, remoteFamily } = socket;
  const { statusCode, statusMessage } = response;
  const headers = response.getHeaders();
  const userId = request.body.userScopeId;

  if (body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
  }
  let post;
  const posts = [];

  if (userId) {
    const category = request?.baseUrl?.replace('/v1/', '') || ' ';
    let nodeUrl = url.split('/');

    nodeUrl = nodeUrl[1].split('?');
    const subcategory = phproutes[category]?.find((x) => x.nodeapi === 
  nodeUrl[0]).subcategory || '';
    const phproute = phproutes[category]?.find((x) => x.nodeapi === 
  nodeUrl[0]).phproutes || '';

    if (subcategory !== '') {
      if (nodeUrl[0] !== 'get-team-invitations') {
        const {
          requestParams,
          requestQuery,
          requestBody,
        } = requestParameters(request.params, request.query, request.body);
        // if (response.statusCode == !304) //no changes in response

        post = {
          createdTime: moment.now(),
          processingTime: Date.now() - requestStart,
          action: url || '',
          subcategory,
          phproute,
          category,
          userId,
          code: body.code || 200,
          requestParams,
          requestQuery,
          requestBody,
          message: body.message || 'Success',
          error: body.error || '',
          method,
        };
        posts.push(post);
        recentVisitedModel.insertManyPosts(posts);
      }
    }
  }
 } catch (error) {
  // console.log(error)
 }
};

const requestParameters = (requestParams, requestQuery, requestBody) => {
delete requestQuery.userScopeName;
delete requestBody.userScopeId;
delete requestBody.userScopeEmail;
delete requestBody.userScopeName;
delete requestBody.userScopeMaxAccountCount;
delete requestBody.userScopeMaxMemberCount;
delete requestBody.userScopeAvailableNetworks;
delete requestBody.userScopeMaxScheduleCount;
delete requestBody.userScopeIsAdmin;

return { requestParams, requestQuery, requestBody };
};

 next();
};
```

I am new to this and do not see the reason why this error comes up here? There seems to be no '.' dot there in the code.

If this is something connected to the version, then my node version is v12.22.6
Npm is 6.14.15

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax (request?.baseUrl?.replace) that you are trying to use is called **Optional Chaining** and it is not supported in older versions of Node. You need to upgrade your Node version to at least v14.

You can find the list of supported platforms and their version [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility).